# Correct interpretation of the zero conditional mean assumption in the linear regression model

Tags: regression, econometrics, linear-model, assumptions, conditional-expectation

In many books the population linear regression model $Y = \langle \beta, X \rangle + U$ has the following "zero conditional mean assumption" (here $Y,X,U$ are random variables; let's also suppose that the i.i.d. assumption for $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}$ holds, so we can drop index $i$):

$$E[U|X] = 0.$$

The problem is that $E[U|X]$ is a random variable, so I see at least three possible interpretations of this equality and I want to know which of them is true (if any):

1. Equality $E[U|X] = 0$ is equivalent to the expression $E[U|X=x] = 0, ~~\forall x \in R$, where $R$ is the range of $X$.
2. Equality $E[U|X] = 0$ is equivalent to the expression $E[U|X=x] = 0, ~~\forall x \in S$, where $S$ is the support of $X$ (i.e. $S = \{x \in \mathcal{X}: f_X(x) \gt 0\}$, where $f_X$ is a pdf of $X$).
3. Equality $E[U|X] = 0$ should be interpreted as the expression $P(E[U|X]=0)=1$, i.e. it holds with probability one.
4. Equality $E[U|X] = 0$ is equivalent to something else?

For me, expression 2 seems more suitable, but very often in the statistics literature the expression $Z = c$ (where $Z$ is some r.v. and $c$ is some constant number) is interpreted as an equality that holds with probability one, i.e. this expression often means that $P(Z=c) = 1$ (like in 3.).

**So, what is the correct interpretation of the equality $E[U|X] = 0$?**

Comment: (1) and (2) are changes of notation that make sense when $X$ has a discrete distribution.   (3) is a way of stating $E[U\mid X]=0$ almost surely, which is understood when $X$ does not have a discrete distribution, because that requires a measure-theoretic construction in which conditional expectations are defined only up to sets of measure zero anyway.

Comment: @whuber, so are they all valid, with (1) and (2) for discrete and (3) for continuous random variables? Are they *the* ways to understand $\mathbb{E}(U|X)=0$?

Comment: @Richard It's hard to see what would not be valid about a mere change of notation! I find (2) to be strange, because it uses notation designed for discrete distributions but refers to continuous distributions (having a pdf). That's not a good idea. I'm sure there are other ways to understand what a zero conditional expectation means, depending on what assumptions you make.  For instance, in the case of ordinary least squares regression with Normal errors, this is often formulated as stating that the *unconditional* expectations of the errors are zero and the errors are independent.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. For me unconditional expectation is easier to understand, but this question about the conditional expectation is one I found interesting and nontrivial. I do not remember ever considering it explicitly myself, and when confronted with it I found it challenging.

Comment: @Richard The whole concept of regression is based on conditional distributions.  Given a design matrix $X,$ a response $Y,$ a class of functions $\mathcal F,$ and a class of distributions $\Theta$ partially parameterized by values of functions in $\mathcal F,$ we seek an $f\in\mathcal F$ and $\theta\in\Theta$ for which the distribution of $Y$ conditional on $X$ is one of those in $\Theta$ with parameter $f(X)$ where $f\in\mathcal F.$ With no restrictions on $\mathcal F$ or $\Theta,$ *the* regression is the conditional distribution of $Y,$ usually simplified to its expectation $E[Y\mid X].$

Comment: @whuber, technically I consider range of the random variable as the set which contains all values that this random variable can have (including points of zero probability, such that $P(X=x) = 0$). So for me (1) and (2) are not just change of notation, and it seems (1) is not suitable for interpretation of the conditional expectation (even in discrete case). Next, in (2) pdf should be interpreted as pmf if $X$ is discrete (sorry, I should mention about it in the OP).

Comment: Finally, expression from (2) in the continuous case, according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Continuous_random_variables), should be interpreted as $\displaystyle \operatorname{E} (U \mid X=x) =  \frac{1}{f_{X}(x)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u f_{U,X}(u,x) \mathrm{d}u = 0, ~~ \forall x \in S$, where $S$ is the support of $X$. To avoid measure-theoretic difficulties it seems that we should require this equality not for all $x \in S$ but almost everywhere on $S$ instead (we should exclude points where $F'_X(x)$ doesn't exist if there are such points).

Comment: @whuber, thanks again. I had no problem with $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ for any concrete value $x$, but now I will also be better informed about what $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ is.